# Does "Let me know if you have any questions." mean "reply only if you have a question"?

Tags: email

Does "Let me know if you have any questions" mean that there is no need to reply unless you have a question?

I get informational emails sometimes that end with some form of "Let me know if you have any questions" or "Let me know with any questions", for this specific instance it's my landlord telling me about scheduled maintenance of the elevators.

Should I reply with a short thank you or should I **not** reply anything unless I have a question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with writing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question is slightly off-topic for this site, but my understanding is;
**Yes**

It *probably* means that (in this case your landlord) only expects a reply if there are actual questions. However, it is most likely not in any way problematic to reply with a "Thank you".

Sure, any person or correspondence is unique, so your landlord may expect a reply to any informative mail.

I'd say go ahead and reply, with or without questions, if that feels natural to you. If you want to be sure, ask if your landlord expects a reply to such mails.